# Return String array from C++ DLL to VBA(Excel)

Tags: c++, vba, excel

I created a C++ DLL which take an empty array as VARIANT. I will run some sql query inside DLL and store output in empty array. When I tried this, excel crashes.

My VBA call :

```
Dim outArray(17) As Variant
bo = GetData_V(dbFilePath, id, inArray, outArray, counter)
```

and function is defined as

```
Declare Function GetData_V& Lib "xyz.dll" (ByVal path As String, ByRef inputArr() As String, ByRef output As Variant, ByRef id As Integer)
```

C++ Implementation :

```
        CComSafeArray<VARIANT> out_sa(nCount);
        HRESULT hr;
        for (LONG i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++)
        {
            CComVariant variant = CComVariant(outputCustom[i]);
            hr = out_sa.SetAt(i,variant);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        CComVariant(out_sa).Detach(outputArray);
```

Where outputCustom is defined as

```
outputCustom = new char*[nCount+1];
```

and has string values.

When I try to run it, Excel crashes. I don't know how to return outputArray back to VBA.

Comment: your function definition does not show a return variable type

Comment: have you successfully written a dll that accepts a single integer and returns a single integer?

Comment: @jsotola when I tried to add a return type, it shows 'expected end of statement.' . I tried putting a fullstop but still giving error. Also I haven't tried returning a integer.

Comment: You have declared your function to return a `Long` (i.e. the `&` on the end of `GetData_V&`) - are you doing so?  Also, your declaration is defining the parameters to be `ByVal path As String, ByVal path As String, ByRef inputArr() As String, ByRef output As Variant, ByRef id As Integer` (with `path` repeated?) but your call (i.e. `dbFilePath, id, inArray, outArray, counter`) doesn't seem to match that.

Comment: you have to be able to create and use a simplest possible dll before doing anything more complex. that way you have very minimal debugging in order to make it work. ... once it works, add more calling arguments... then finally add the return parameter

Comment: @YowE3K Sorry, thats by mistake and i removed '&'.

Comment: You have now edited your code to show that you are passing 5 parameters but declaring it as having only 4 parameters.  It would probably be best if you post an actual MCVE, including the parts of your VBA code where you declare all the variables you are using as parameters.  Without that, there really isn't enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I return String array from `C++ DLL` to `VBA`:
I changed my `VBA` function declaration to this :

```
Declare Function GetData_V Lib "xyz.dll" (ByVal path As String, ByVal id As String, ByRef inputArr() As String, ByRef output() As String) As Variant()
```

C++ implementation : 
Changed return type of `C++` function to `SAFEARRAY*` and modified the code as follow:

```
   SafeArrayLock(*outputArray); 
    for (LONG i = 0; i < countElements; i++)
    {
        CComBSTR bstr = CComBSTR(outputCustom[i]);
        SafeArrayPutElement(*outputArray, &i, bstr);
    }
    SafeArrayUnlock(*outputArray); 

    delete [] outputCustom;

    return *outputArray;
```